# How to limit a 350W electric motor to 200W

Tags: amplifier, transformer, motor

Current system: Battery: 36V, Motor: max 350W, DC Motor. There is also a controller to increase/decrease motor speed.

Without making any (other) changes in the current system, can I introduce a 36V to 24V [1V to 36V range can be set] step down converter, 200W/15A max output to lower the maximum wattage of the motor to 200W by lowering the voltage till it reaches a max output of 200W?

If so, then where do I place this converter? Directly after the battery and before the controller or just before the motor after the controller?

Finally, will there be any risk of blowing up the converter given that 200W max, or does the reduced voltage ensure the previous max (350W) cannot be reached anyway?

If I need to clarify something, please just ask instead of voting to close this question. I can always add information.

Comment: If your motor is rated to handle 350W maximum, it doesn't mean you have to always drive it at 350W. You can drive it at a lower power depending on your application. And you need to place your DC-DC converter before the motor driver

Comment: @PrathikPrashanth Thank you very much. Yes I realize that, but I want to limit the max power to 200W at peak. So the DC-DC convertor idea would work? When you say "before the motor driver" is that after the controller? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on the possibilities of your motor driver. Each PWM motor driver itself acts like a buck converter, reducing the input voltage with regard setpoint speed. But this still doesn't provide a mechanism to limit the current and power. You have to have a motor driver with a current limit that can be adjusted.

Introducing yet another step down converter won't help.

Comment: I think I understand. So how do I search online for a DC motor driver with adjustable current limiter? How is such a thing called?

Comment: @RoelVandePaar You said, you already have a motor driver. It depends on used motor - nominal voltage/current , type of control 1 quadrant - just one direction, 2-quadrant, 4 quadrant (both directions and generator mode), speed control- encoder, position control ,... We don't have a crystal ball to understand what you have and what you want to achieve, so you could expand the question wit more details.